# Is there any way to swap the fn (function) and control keys in linux on an macbook pro?

Tags: linux, keyboard, remap

I don't care if this is done in the bios or a kernel module or software.  Is there any way at all to do make the 'fn' key act as 'control' and the 'control' key act as 'fn' in linux running on a macbook pro?

PS. You can do this with software in OSX with the application KeyRemap4MacBook.

Comment: Use this kernel module: https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched

Comment: Precisely what I needed to do (on elementaryOS 6.0) was documented here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156629/278323, where it _is_ "on topic."

Answer (score 2):

Try the command "xev" and press the Fn key.

On my computer (Lenovo T60), I see this in the terminal when I press the Fn key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x6d, subw 0x0, time 2266123481, (652,782), root:(655,915),
    state 0x10, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp),
```

So the Fn key is keycode 151. My left control is 37. Then you can remap, now knowing the key codes they generate.

https://web.archive.org/web/20090202093048/http://www.columbia.edu/~djv/docs/keyremap.html

Comment: The Fn key on a Mac does not generate an event in xev.

Comment: The link does not work

Comment: @JimmyKane, Try this link https://web.archive.org/web/20090202093048/http://www.columbia.edu/~djv/docs/keyremap.html

Comment: If the key does not generate any event, what should I do? Any ideas.

Comment: This project solved the issue for me: https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched